# active-directory-xamarin-native-v2 sample project from Microsoft for Xamarin Forms is not working in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I am working on office365 authentication , took the code from github, for android build it is working fine, but in iOS not getting data response (token) from office365.

project link - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-xamarin-native-v2

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    async void OnSignInSignOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        IEnumerable<IAccount> accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
        try
        {
            if (btnSignInSignOut.Text == "Sign in")
            {
                // let's see if we have a user in our belly already
                try
                {
                    IAccount firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
                    authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilent(App.Scopes, firstAccount)
                                          .ExecuteAsync();
                    await RefreshUserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign out"; });
                }
                catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
                {
                    try
                    {

                        authResult = await App.PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(App.Scopes)
                                                  .WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.ParentWindow)
                                                  .ExecuteAsync();

                        await RefreshUserDataAsync(authResult.AccessToken);
                        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign out"; });
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex2)
                    {
                        slUser.IsVisible = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                while (accounts.Any())
                {
                    await App.PCA.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                    accounts = await App.PCA.GetAccountsAsync();
                }

                slUser.IsVisible = false;
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => { btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign in"; });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }

    public async Task RefreshUserDataAsync(string token)
    {
        //get data from API
        slUser.IsVisible = true;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me");
        message.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);
        string responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            JObject user = JObject.Parse(responseString);

            slUser.IsVisible = true;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {

                lblDisplayName.Text = user["displayName"].ToString();
                lblGivenName.Text = user["givenName"].ToString();
                lblId.Text = user["id"].ToString();
                lblSurname.Text = user["surname"].ToString();
                lblUserPrincipalName.Text = user["userPrincipalName"].ToString();

                // just in case
                btnSignInSignOut.Text = "Sign out";
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Something went wrong with the API call", responseString, "Dismiss");
        }
    }
}
}
```

I should get the same as android build, but in iOS not getting token from office365 server, seems like certificate issue, Below lines I found which are need to follow, in order to work in iOS

Also, in order to make the token cache work and have the AcquireTokenSilentAsync work multiple steps must be followed :

1)Enable Keychain access in your Entitlements.plist file and specify in the Keychain Groups your bundle identifier.

2)In your project options, on iOS Bundle Signing view, select your Entitlements.plist file for the Custom Entitlements field.

3) When signing a certificate, make sure XCode uses the same Apple Id.

Above are from Microsoft website

below is Entitlements.plist file details -
keychain-access-groups I am using $(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.oauth.office365 where com.oauth.office365 is my bundle identifier

Comment: can you specify if you are getting any error message ?

Comment: I am receiving no token response

Comment: In android it is working fine

Comment: Getting no error message